# Create folders tree logic simplification

Tags: windows, powershell, script

I just started learning some PowerShell and taking my first steps.
I'm training to create directories.

I wrote this code below which works, but I want to ask how it can be further simplified and also help me continue to learn and expand my PowerShell skills?

```
$branch1 = (@('Fox','Wolf','Cat','Cow','Snake','Elephant') | ForEach-Object { New-Item (Join-Path 'C:\tree\Animals\' $_) -ItemType Directory -force })
$branch2 = (@('Chair','Cupboard','Sofa','Table','Bed','Dresser') | ForEach-Object { New-Item (Join-Path 'C:\tree\Furniture\' $_) -ItemType Directory -force })
$branch3 = (@('Mercury','Venus','Earth','Mars','Jupiter','Saturn') | ForEach-Object { New-Item (Join-Path 'C:\tree\Planets\' $_) -ItemType Directory -force })
$FolderTree = $branch1 + $branch2 + $branch3
if ($FolderTree) { Write-Host "All sorted out."}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Potential simplified adjustments

1. Set the array data types explicitly as variables up top.
2. Create a [function](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-functions.html) and
   build the `New-Item` command within it to accept two arguments per
   the values passed to the function call at execution time to
   dynamically build the paths for it to create.
3. Lastly, `ForEach-Object` loop over each array, explicitly define the
   first parameter on the function call, and have the second parameter
   be the iterated value of the array per the `$_` placeholder (e.g.
   `_Main "animals" $_;`).

**Note:** Some people might consider using `%` for the `ForEach-Object` alias simplified too so I used that in the example PowerShell below since you ask about simplification in particular.

### PowerShell

```
$animals = 'Fox','Wolf','Cat','Cow','Snake','Elephant';
$furniture = 'Chair','Cupboard','Sofa','Table','Bed','Dresser';
$planets = 'Mercury','Venus','Earth','Mars','Jupiter','Saturn';

Function _Main (){
    New-Item "C:\tree\$($args[0])\$($args[1])" -ItemType Directory -Force;
    };

$animals | % { _Main "animals" $_; };
$furniture | % { _Main "furniture" $_; };
$planets  | % { _Main "planets" $_; };
```

> #### PowerShell (different variation)
>
> ```
> $animals = 'Fox','Wolf','Cat','Cow','Snake','Elephant';
> $furniture = 'Chair','Cupboard','Sofa','Table','Bed','Dresser';
> $planets = 'Mercury','Venus','Earth','Mars','Jupiter','Saturn';
>
> Function _Main (){
>     New-Item "$($args[0])" -ItemType Directory -Force;
>     };
>
> $animals | % { _Main "C:\tree\animals\$_"; };
> $furniture | % { _Main "C:\tree\furniture\$_"; };
> $planets  | % { _Main "C:\tree\planets\$_"; };
> ```

### Supporting Resources

- [PowerShell Functions](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-functions.html)

  > At its most basic a function is simply the function keyword followed
  > by a name for the function, then some code inside a pair of curly
  > braces.
  >
  > ```
  > function Add-Numbers {  $args[0] + $args[1] }
  >
  > PS C:\> Add-Numbers 5 10 
  > 15
  > ```
- [about_Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.2)
- [PowerShell Operators $( ) @( ) :: &](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to the helpful approach of @Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style.

This approach uses a hashtable and validates errors of `New-Item`.
It's simplified in terms of structure, dynamic and readability. Not in terms of one-liners / less code.

```
$basePath = 'C:\tree\'

# a hashtable with a key and value pair
# the key or value could also be a path, see example 'Food\Vegetables' below
$directoryTree = @{
    # Key         = Value(s)
    Animals       = 'Fox', 'Wolf', 'Cat', 'Cow', 'Snake', 'Elephant'
    Furniture     = 'Chair', 'Cupboard', 'Sofa', 'Table', 'Bed', 'Dresser'
    Planets       = 'Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth', 'Mars', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn'
    'Food\Fruits' = 'Berries\Banana', 'Berries\Watermelon', 'Apple', 'Pineapple'
}

# reset error indicator of New-Item
$newItemCommandError = $null

# loop through the keys. Always use ".psbase." to avoid the hashtable property "Keys" gets overriden by a key named "Keys"
foreach ($directory in $directoryTree.psbase.Keys) {
    # loop through the values of current key
    foreach ($subDirectory in $directoryTree[$directory]) {
        # build full path by concatenating Join-Path via Pipe(s).
        # can be simplified as of PS7+: "Join-Path $basePath $directory $subDirectory"
        $fullPath = Join-Path $basePath $directory | Join-Path -ChildPath $subDirectory
        # ErrorVariable +'newItemCommandError' acts as an indicator for errors
        $null = New-Item $fullPath -ItemType Directory -Force -ErrorVariable +'newItemCommandError'
    }
}

if (-not $newItemCommandError) {
    Write-Host 'All sorted out.'
}
```

**Same code without comments and fruits:**

```
$basePath = 'C:\tree\'
$directoryTree = @{
    Animals   = 'Fox', 'Wolf', 'Cat', 'Cow', 'Snake', 'Elephant'
    Furniture = 'Chair', 'Cupboard', 'Sofa', 'Table', 'Bed', 'Dresser'
    Planets   = 'Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth', 'Mars', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn'
}

$newItemCommandError = $null
foreach ($directory in $directoryTree.psbase.Keys) {
    foreach ($subDirectory in $directoryTree[$directory]) {
        $fullPath = Join-Path $basePath $directory | Join-Path -ChildPath $subDirectory
        $null     = New-Item $fullPath -ItemType Directory -Force -ErrorVariable +'newItemCommandError'
    }
}

if (-not $newItemCommandError) {
    Write-Host 'All sorted out.'
}
```